# Android, receive intents inside the framework

Tags: android, frameworks, android-intent, android-activity, nfc

I'm trying to figure out how to recieve intents inside the android framework. To be more specific, I want to register myself as a receiver for NFC intents inside the "PasswordUnlockScreen" found under "com.android.internal.policy.impl". The problem is that I'm not inside an activity context.

Is there any way how I can be informed of new NFC intents without having an activity context?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to the constructor of PasswordUnlockScreen context parameter is passed. The second option is to use `getContext()` method to get context. The example you can also find in this file.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need an Activity context to receive NFC intents. Furthermore, when the screen is locked, NFC is turned off: i.e. no intents will be sent anyway.

Comment: I already patched the NfcService, so it will sent intents even if the screen is locked. So that's not a problem. But there is really no way of recieving intents from outside an activity context? And i can also not dynamically create an activity, right? I have to declare it in the Manifestfile, which is not present in the framework itself.